# Delete user from frontend

Tags: users, actions, user-meta, front-end

Hi I am working on a frontend admin where a user must be able to delete his account. `current_user()` is a custom made function of me that retrieves the user meta data.

Does anyone know how I can make this work?

```
echo '<a class="remove" href="' . get_permalink() . '?remove_account">' . __( 'Click here to remove your account' ) . '</a>';

// Remove account
function terminate_account() {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/user.php' );
    wp_delete_user( current_user( 'ID' ) );
}

if( isset( $_GET['remove_account'] ) ) {
    add_action( 'init', 'terminate_account' );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken directly form [the `wp_delete_user` documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_user):

```
if(is_user_logged_in() && !empty($_GET['DeleteMyAccount'])) {
    add_action('init', 'remove_logged_in_user');
}

function remove_logged_in_user() {
    require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/user.php' );
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    wp_delete_user( $current_user->ID );
}
```

Things to note:

- Your code didn't check if the user was logged in or not
- by the time you're printing the remove user link, the init action has already happened and finished, so your delete user wouldn't work. That part of the code needs to be ran earlier, say in functions.php or a plugin

edit:

If you can place this in your themes function file:

```
add_action('init', 'remove_logged_in_user');

function remove_logged_in_user() {
    require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/user.php' );
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $success = wp_delete_user( $current_user->ID );
    wp_die('wp delete gave: <pre>"'.print_r($success).'"</pre>');
}
```

Comment: I have tried it in functions.php but got the same result..

Comment: and you've verified that wp_delete_user is being called? what happens if you place `wp_die('testing');` at the top of the `remove_logged_in_user` function?

Comment: Tried that, nothing happens..

Comment: And thats with the URL `/?remove_account=true` ? Also what's the return value of `wp_delete_user` ? That wp_die doesn't get executed suggests that the function never runs, hence the user never getting deleted

Comment: Yes that is with `/?remove_account=true`. No return value in my opinion..

Comment: Can you post the output rather than describing it? It saves time

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13578/discussion-between-robbert-and-tom-j-nowell)

Comment: I can't because nothing is happening when I click the link. I tried your last edit but there is still nothing happening..

Comment: so clearly it never even attempts to delete the user, the code doesnt fail, it's simply never executed. Adding a piece of code that runs on the init hook is a pretty basic thing, I'm finding it difficult to understand why it's failing to happen. You're not doing something you haven't mentioned, like trying to run this on an AJAX hook? What I've posted **should** work, if it doesn't then there's something you're not sharing or doing wrong that I cant see here

Comment: I have required a file in functions.php where I use the remove function in. This function is also placed in a add_shortcode() function. In my opinion these are the only things I have not shared. (I have also tried your code directly in functions.php)

Comment: can you continue in chat?

Comment: My reputation is too low to start the chat.